# React - onClick event not working correctly

Tags: reactjs, parameters, onclick

I'm attempting to pass an onClick function as a prop to a child component in React. However, nothing is being logged to the console when the button is clicked. For now I'm just trying to console log to make sure the event is actually firing.

Any Ideas?

```
class App extends React.Component {

togglePallets = (pallet) => {
    console.log('test');
  }

render() {
return (
        <div className="mainWrapper">
          <div className="mainContainer">
            <div>
              <img src="images/picture-of-me.jpg" alt="Me"></img>
            </div>
          </div>
          <SideBar toggle={this.togglePallets} showPallets={[this.state.showAboutPallet, this.state.showLanguagesPallet, 
          this.state.showProjectsPallet, this.state.showContactPallet]}/>
          {this.state.showAboutPallet && <AboutPallet />}
          {this.state.showAboutPallet && <LanguagesPallet />}
          {this.state.showAboutPallet && <ProjectsPallet />}
          {this.state.showAboutPallet && <ContactPallet />}
        </div>
      );
}
}

function SideBar(props) {
  return (
    <div className="sideBarContainer">
        <Button icon={faUser} showAboutPallet={props.showPallets[0]} onClick={props.toggle}/>
    </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Hm, I don't think that the prop passing is the problem. I setup a minimal example [here](https://codesandbox.io/embed/stoic-river-tgcz6) (just with default button) and the `onClick` event is working (See console). Could you also post the code of your `Button` component?

Comment: Post `Button` component also.

Comment: In `Button` component you should have `<button onClick={()=>props.onClick('data')}>Button</button>`

Comment: Oh wow, thank you both. Looks like I needed to pass the prop one level deeper to the actual <button> element. I was trying to attach the onClick event to the component itself and that appears to have been the issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you have written is correct. But we can try it in another way using an arrow function.

```
onClick={(e) => props.toggle(e,data)}
```

And, make relevant changes in toggle function, so it may support multiple arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Change your togglePallets to any of the below

```
togglePallets() {
    console.log("test");
  };
```

If you want to access event then

```
togglePallets(event) {
    console.log("test");
  };
```

Or

```
togglePallets=event =>{
    console.log("teeventst");
  };
```